# Tagging history

Tags: discussion, tagging

Existing tags: [history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) (32), [history-of-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-islam) (31), [islam--history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam--history) (2), [islamic-history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-history) (1).

Surely only [history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is needed. The "of Islam" can be assumed. I think the two smaller tags should be edited to [history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) by hand, but [history-of-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-islam) should probaly be delt with by moderator tools to avoid flooding the front page with a bunch of revised posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've chosen to just merge the whole array since I can't think of any conceivable (on-topic) need to keep the tags separated.  Didn't bother to make any synonyms, since one would need to go through "history" to get to "history-of-islam" anyway, whereas the "islam--history" and "islamic-history" obviously don't get enough play to worry about.

Comment: We seem to have one hold-out: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5444/156 is still `islamic-history`. (Could possibly be some sort of caching issue, but the other tag lists now appear empty.)

Comment: Oops.  Fixed it.